# mod_rewrite: redirect from subdomain to main domain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirection

I have two domains - domain.com and forum.domain.com that points to the same directory.

I'd like redirect all request from forum.domain.com to domain.com (for example: forum.domain.com/foo to domain.com/forum/foo) without changing address in addres bar (hidden redirect).

I wrote something like this and put it into .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on   

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.example\.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/forum/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php/$1 [L]
```

That works only if I add Redirect directive:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/forum/$1 [R,L]
```

But it changes previous address in address bar.

**EDIT:**

Ok, let's make it simple. I added those two lines at the end of the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on my local computer:

```
127.0.0.3   foo.net
127.0.0.3   forum.foo.net
```

Now, I created two virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost foo.net:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
    ServerName foo.net
DocumentRoot "C:/usr/src/foo"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost forum.foo.net:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
    ServerName forum.foo.net
DocumentRoot "C:/usr/src/foo"
</VirtualHost>
```

..and directory called "foo", where i put two files: .htaccess and index.php.

Index.php:

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.foo\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/forum/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^forum\.foo\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php/$1 [L]
```

When I type address *http://forum.foo.net/test* in address bar, it displays */forum/test* which is good. http://foo.net/a/b/c shows */a/b/c* which is good. **But!** *http://forum.foo.net/* displays empty value (should display */forum*).

Comment: domain.com and forum.domain.com were two seperate virtual hosts, but not anymore :) They are the same IP addres - ServerAlias. However, I'd my old links work as usual without redirecting (without HTTP header 301)

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_proxy and use the `P` flag instead.

Comment: Hmm, does not work. Could you give me an example?